# Document Provider / File Provider - Location Settings iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, ios-extensions

iOS 11 revolutionized the Document Provider extension with File Provider [Apple Documentation on Choosing File Providers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/creating_file_providers_for_multiple_versions_of_ios)

My question is on the UX when searching for locations on iOS 10 vs iOS 11. Previous to iOS 11, a user could manage their locations: after an initial browsing of a desired location, they would select that location with a switch control to add it to the initial provider list that is presented. This essentially removes a extra step as the user would not need to browse again for a commonly selected location. Instead, it would be added to beneath Cloud and Photo Library in the initial list.

It appears that this functionality has been removed in iOS 11. The user must always browse from the initial list of locations. Does this appear to be the case or has anyone have experience that allows a user to add a location? Many thanks.